# Rewriting "outside" URL

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm looking for a solution to replace all the links from a curl response to my site.

Lets say my site is: example.com, then I make a CURL request to site.com.
site.com has various links:

```
   <a href="http://smthing.com">Something!</a>
   <some html>......
   <a href="http://google.com">Google!</a>
   <more html>
   <a href="#" onclick="window.location.href='http://somethingElse.com'">Something else</a>
```

My goal is to prefix all the links with: example.com/?url={THE URL OF THE LINK} (AKA my site).

My current solution uses regexp to "catch" and process all the links.
This works most of the time, but from time to time I encounter a non-valid HTML that fails the regex.
The regex has another disadvantage: I can't catch  onclick="" actions and different link scenarios.

I heard several solutions such as rewrite and reverse proxy. Any of them can work to achieve my goal?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should absolutely be able to use regex for that.  However, your code will have to be a little more robust to handle inline scripting.  Analyze a large sample of anchor attributes to determine all the possible link formats, over and above /href=""/ and /window.location.href/.
You will also have to parse referenced script files to see what the event handlers hold.